# How to get the hex value of Russian string in c++

Tags: php, c++, hex

I have some php code that takes a Russian string and converts it to hex by doing the following:

```
$string = "Ф";
$hex='';
for ($i=0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
  $hex .= dechex(ord($string[$i]));
}
echo $hex;
```

This produces the correct output that I am looking for:

> d0a4

I am trying to reproduce these results in C++, but have had no success. It seems like c++ is returning a hex value of 424 if I do something like this:

```
char16_t strg(L"Ф");
```

or

```
wstring strg(L"Ф");
```

or

```
short strg(L'Ф');
```

Please help me reproduce a value of `d0a4` in C++. Thanks.

Comment: How are you doing the conversion?  Have you tried using [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/to_bytes)?

Comment: Sorry Nathan completely missed your comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
// wide character data
std::wstring wstr =  L"Ф";  

// wide to UTF-8
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>> conv1;
std::string u8str = conv1.to_bytes(wstr);
std::cout << "UTF-8 conversion produced " << u8str.size() << " bytes:\n";
hex_print(u8str);

// wide to UTF-16le
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>> conv2;
std::string u16str = conv2.to_bytes(wstr);
std::cout << "UTF-16le conversion produced " << u16str.size() << " bytes:\n";
hex_print(u16str);
```

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert/to_bytes

Comment: Thanks, looks like the UTF-8 section produces the correct result.